# How to fetch list of group from Microsoft personal account

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

How to fetch lists of groups and send message to group using API from Microsoft personal account.Can you please provide me some suggestions or doc for above query.

Comment: Sending message to groups, which kind of group? Chat group in microsoft teams? If so, this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Groups don't exist in Microsoft Personal Accounts context because there is just on personal account. That is why every endpoint in [Groups Resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0) says not supported for `Delegated (personal Microsoft account)`.

If you are trying to send an email to a group from a personal Microsoft account or a work account, you can do that using [Send Mail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) with the groups alias in you `toRecipients` or  `ccRecipients` in which case the groups till exists in a tenant that you cant access unless you are a guest user there with your personal account.